# How can I consume data type of Rc<RefCell<T>> in struct?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement an linked list for learning purposes. std::cell::RefCell and stc::rc::{Rc, Weak} are mainly used to store data into the list instance. Now I'm implementing *fn pop*, which consumes and returns a value in the first location in the list, but I don't know how to consume a value wrapped with Rc and RefCell.

Here is my code:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct DbNode<T> {
    data: T,
    next: Option<Rc<RefCell<DbNode<T>>>>,
    prev: Option<Weak<RefCell<DbNode<T>>>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct DbList<T> {
    first: Option<Rc<RefCell<DbNode<T>>>>,
    last: Option<Weak<RefCell<DbNode<T>>>>,
}

pub fn push_front(&mut self, data: T) {
    match self.first.take() {
        Some(e) => {
            let new_front = Rc::new(RefCell::new(DbNode {
                data,
                next: Some(e.clone()),
                prev: None,
            }));
            let mut me = e.borrow_mut();
            me.prev = Some(Rc::downgrade(&new_front));
            self.first = Some(new_front);
        },
        None => {
            let new_data = Rc::new(RefCell::new(DbNode {
                data,
                next: None,
                prev: None,
            }));
            self.last = Some(Rc::downgrade(&new_data));
            self.first = Some(new_data);
        },
    }
}

pub fn push_back(&mut self, data: T) {
    match self.last.take() {
        Some(l) => {
            let new_back = Rc::new(RefCell::new(DbNode {
                data,
                next: None,
                prev: Some(l.clone()),
            }));
            let st = Weak::upgrade(&l).unwrap();
            let mut ml = st.borrow_mut();
            self.last = Some(Rc::downgrade(&new_back));
            ml.next = Some(new_back);
        },
        None => {
            let new_data = Rc::new(RefCell::new(DbNode {
                data,
                next: None,
                prev: None,
            }));
            self.last = Some(Rc::downgrade(&new_data));                
            self.first = Some(new_data);
        },
    }
}

pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
    match self.first.take() {
        Some(f) => {
            // How can I??
            // let result = Some(f.into_inner().data);
            // result
        },
        None => None,
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to return the inner 'data' value in the struct **DbNode** located in the 'first' in struct **DbList** and set **None** to the 'first' in which the data to be consumed located if 'next' is **None**, else set 'next' to 'first'.
At first, I tried to consume the inner value with using **Rc::downcast**, but the type of 'f' in matching block was 'RefCell', not 'Rc', then I tried to use RefCell::into_inner(), but compiler says:

> cannot move out of an `Rc`
> move occurs because value has type `std::cell::RefCell<ds::dll::DbNode<T>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

I totally understand what this means, but I don't know what I should do. What is the correct way to do it??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were close. Use [`Rc::try_unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.try_unwrap):

> Returns the inner value, if the `Rc` has exactly one strong reference. Otherwise, an `Err` is returned with the same `Rc` that was passed in. This will succeed even if there are outstanding weak references.

```
pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
    match self.first.take() {
        Some(f) => {
            match Rc::try_unwrap(f) {
                Ok(refcell) => {
                    // you can do refcell.into_inner here
                    Some(refcell.into_inner().data)
                },
                Err(_) => {
                    // another Rc still exists so you cannot take ownership of the value
                    None
                }
            }
        },
        None => None,
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! I have an additional question: how can I get Rc, not RefCell in the option matching? As I know, it is RefCell because it is automatically dereferenced. If I want to get Rc, what can I do for it?

Comment: @ParkCheolu I don't understand, `f` in this sample is an `Rc`.

Comment: really? if so, my Visual Studio is weird. When I type dot after 'f', the IDE shows a list of RefCell's methods, not of Rc...

Comment: That's due to dereferencing, `f` is an `Rc` but `Rc`s implement `Deref` for their inner value providing direct access to fields and methods. This is done transparently by the compiler. This is also used for `Box`s and even `Vec`s.

Comment: I got it. You are correct. I just checked Rc::try_unwrap in docs and it accepts  Rc only. So, "`f` is Rc and I can treat it as both Rc and its inner value because of `Deref`" is all correct?